# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout in Recycler Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using `Recycle` to get data from JSon URL include `TextView` and `ImageView`
I have some classes: `Activity`, `POJO` and `Adapter`.

This my source code: (**UPDATED**)

```
public class PartOneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editTextSearcch;

List<GetDataAdapter> GetDataAdapter1;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;
String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = "myURL";
String JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME = "name";
String JSON_IMAGE_URL = "thumb";
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest ;
RequestQueue requestQueue ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppThemeRed);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    initEditTextSearch();
    initRecyclerView();
}

private void initEditTextSearch() {
    /*mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));*/

    editTextSearcch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
    editTextSearcch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void initRecyclerView() {

    /*
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(createItemList());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    */

    GetDataAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    // recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);
    // JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();
    json_data_web_call();

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new HidingScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHide() {
            hideViews();
        }

        @Override
        public void onShow() {
            showViews();
        }
    });
}

private void hideViews() {
    editTextSearcch.animate().translationY(-editTextSearcch.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2));
}

private void showViews() {
    editTextSearcch.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));
}



public void json_data_web_call(){

    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL,

            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    json_parse_data_after_webcall(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

public void json_parse_data_after_webcall(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

        GetDataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapter();

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {

            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitleNamee(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME));

            GetDataAdapter2.setImageServerUrl(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_URL));

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);

    }
    recyclerViewadapter.set(GetDataAdapter1);   //may need to add a setter in adapter
    recyclerViewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, this);
    // recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
  } 
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter class:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 4;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

Context context;
List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter;
ImageLoader imageLoader1;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context){
    super();
    this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {
    if (!isPositionHeader(position)) {
        GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter1 = getDataAdapter.get(position - 1);
        imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader1.get(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(),
                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                        Viewholder.networkImageView,//Server Image
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
                )
        );        Viewholder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(), imageLoader1);

    Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName());
    }
}

public int getDataAdapter() {
    return getDataAdapter == null ? 0 : getDataAdapter.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionHeader(position)) {
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    }

    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return getDataAdapter() + 1;
}

private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
    public NetworkImageView networkImageView ;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item) ;

        networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1) ;

    }
}
```

}

When I build I see `Recycler` can not load `TextView` and `ImageView`, and `CatLog` appear an exception following as:

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

How to fix this exception ?

Comment: Method names shouldn't be caps locked, and you can set the adapter before the web request starts

Comment: the recyclerview thinks that you didnt se the adapter because you only set it after you get the data. Initialize it and then create a setter and set the data to adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initilializing the adapter response from request.
Initially adapter set is null.
You need to set

```
recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
```

in `initRecyclerView`

In `json_parse_data_after_webcall`
You should do

```
recyclerViewadapter.setDataAdapter(GetDataAdapter1) //may need to add a setter in adapter
recyclerViewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

In RecyclerViewAdapter class

```
public setDataAdapter(ArrayList<GetDataAdapter>g){
this.getDataAdapter = g;
}
```

and change recyclerviewAdapter declaration in PartOneActivity to

```
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewadapter;
```

Comment: I have added: recyclerViewadapter.set(GetDataAdapter1) and recyclerViewadapter.notifyDatasetChanged() in json_parse_data_after_webcall method, but it seem no allow (red line)

Comment: which line? set or notify?

Comment: Hi Suraj Rao: I have tried added setter method but it's incorrect for me, I have posted Adapter class, Can you guide for me add setter method

Comment: Can you put the updated class in question? where is the setter in the adapter?

Comment: Hi Suraj Rao, we need to change ArrayList type by List in setDataAdapter and then it worked for me, thank so much :))